# Firebase db.ref is not a function (node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone please tell me what is wrong in my code before I go back to MongoDB?

Project is in Node.js (Next.js)

This is how I set firebase (it works for authentication with Google Login for instance):

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const credentials = {
    ...
}

const firebase = initializeApp(credentials);

export default firebase;
```

then this is my api js file where it throws error "db.ref" is not a function:

```
import firebase from '@/firebase/firebase'
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue, update, child, orderByChild, equalTo, once } from "firebase/database"

export default async (req, res) => {
    const db = getDatabase(firebase);

    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        const body = req.body
        const playlistTracks = body.playlist
        const playlistName = body.name
        const uid = body.uid

        const data = ...

        console.log(data)

            var ref = db.ref().child('users');
            ref.child(uid).orderByChild('n').equalTo(playlistName).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                let listId = snapshot.key;
                db.ref("users/" + uid + "/" + listId).update(data);

                res.send({ risp : 'ok' })
            });
    }
}
```

realtime database structure is:

```
- users
     - <user uid>
          - <playlist uid>
               c: []
               n: "playlist name"
```

so I'm trying to first retrieve the correct playlist by it's name ("n" value) comparing all "n" with the name of the given playlist, then I'd need to update (overwrite) it with my object (data)

**UPDATE:**

So I found the other methods Web version 9 (modular) in the documentation, as suggested by Frank van Puffelen below, but it now thorws a error

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user
> callback. Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they
> are sent to the  client

My code now is like this:

```
try {
    const myQuery = query(ref(db, 'users/' + uid), orderByChild('n'), equalTo(playlistName));
    onChildAdded(myQuery, (data) => {
        let listId = data.key;

        const updates = {};
        updates["users/" + uid + "/" + listId] = dataToUpdate;
        update(ref(db), updates);

        
    }, {
        onlyOnce: true
    });

    res.send({ risp : 'ok' })

} catch (e) {
    res.status(400).end();
}
```

also tried like this, but it's the same error:

```
const myQuery = query(ref(db, 'users/' + uid), orderByChild('n'), equalTo(playlistName));
            onChildAdded(myQuery, (data) => {
                let listId = data.key;

                update(ref(db, "users/" + uid + "/" + listId), dataToUpdate)
                .then(() => {
                    res.send({ risp: 'ok' })
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    res.status(400).end();
                });
                
            }, {
                onlyOnce: true
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the new modular API, so can't use namespaced accessors like `db.ref()` anymore. Instead use `ref(db, 'users')`.

I highly recommend keeping the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) handy while upgrading this code to the new API version, as it has example of the modular and namespaced API side by side. The [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10) is probably also a worthwhile read).

Comment: I found the version 9 of those functions I was missing, thanks, more clear now. I updated with my code now, because I'm now getting a error of http headers, any idea? I'm also using onlyOnce: true to avoid it

Comment: That new error seems quite unrelated to the original problem. The problem is that `onChildAdded` can be called many times, and you can only call `res.send` once.

Comment: thanks, I've created a new thread for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73097442/firebase-warning-exception-was-thrown-by-user-callback-error-err-http-headers